# IOS - newbie can't figure out how to get a button press to show a new screen

Tags: ios, ios5

I have been doing different tutorials and now I can render buttons and do some things with them, but there is something I still don't quite understand in how to get a button to go to a new screen.

I have this main view I render:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *homeToLearn;

- (IBAction)homeToPlanBusiness:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeToLearn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeToMyPlans:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeToSettings:(id)sender;

//[homeToLearn addTarget:self action:@selector(saveButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.navController pushViewController:newLeanController animated:YES]

@end
```

It renders buttons, but what I am trying to do is on press of "homeToLearn" button, I want it to go to a view that I have which is called LearningCenter

How can I do that? I seem to be going in circles and not understanding what needs to really be done.

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Are you confident that your self.navController is not nil? And finally, have you verified that the saveButton: method is being called, and that the problem is actually with the NavController interaction?

Comment: I think you should start here (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457), and do some simple examples.

Comment: @ctrahey yeah you touched on a few points i am confused on. I got the navController from an example. But I am not sure if it is something that is supposed to be in my code and controll all navigation? And yes I am using storyboards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are using storyboards, there is actually a 100% code-free way to accomplish this (and then proper in-code callbacks to extend the app in the future).

In your storyboard, select your "main" view controller, then select the menu item: "Editor" > "Embed In" > "Navigation Controller".

BTW, there is *always* a self.navigationController property available on your viewControllers which will point to the current nab controller if you have one, no need for custom code.

Now, ctrl-drag from your button to another view controller in the storyboard, and select "push" from the pop-over menu.

Congrats, you just created your first "segue"!

These segues can be named, and there are callbacks you can implement in your view controllers to add custom logic when they fire.